# Remove Unnecessary Characters from String PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am new in PHP and in REGEX. I have a string like below

```
{"fileName":"#DH_BCDN_BASE_URL#/fetchdata16/images/fe/ef/b4/feefb4aab5683517f5ff01b5d479bbd7f50e7fa3fb462d259d110c8c8143b921.jpg","width":1000,"height":999}
```

I want String Only After #/ and before ", So its need like below

```
fetchdata16/images/fe/ef/b4/feefb4aab5683517f5ff01b5d479bbd7f50e7fa3fb462d259d110c8c8143b921.jpg
```

I am not getting idea how I can achieve the goal. Anyone here can please help me for same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you can easily parse that out with explode

```
$json = '{"fileName":"#DH_BCDN_BASE_URL#/fetchdata16/images/fe/ef/b4/feefb4aab5683517f5ff01b5d479bbd7f50e7fa3fb462d259d110c8c8143b921.jpg","width":1000,"height":999}';
//parse the json
$json = json_decode($json);
$str = explode("#/", $json->fileName)[1];
echo $str;
```

You can view it here: https://www.tehplayground.com/LlWImdvpR145fE81